# slick Trying to do a filter based on jodaTime DateTime

Tags: scala, datetime, playframework, slick

I get this error in play framework

> could not find implicit value for parameter tt:
>   slick.ast.TypedType[org.joda.time.DateTime]

That hapens If I don't place the following implicit
I placed a implicit to do the conversion after the declaration using: def datain = columnDateTime(jdateColumnType)

```
implicit def jdateColumnType  =
      MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
        dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
        ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime)
    )
```

But this didn't solve the issue in the search where a error occurs: saying that DateTime does not have <=

```
def getLast24HByAddress(address:String) : Future[List[Email]] = {
    val now = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime())
    db.run(
      Emails.filter(_.datain <= DateTime.now.minusDays(1))
    )
  }
```

When I do this with the implicit I get:

> value <= is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[org.joda.time.DateTime]

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this in the class where I define the tables:

```
/**
 * Mapping for using Joda Time.
 */
implicit def dateTimeMapping = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, java.sql.Timestamp](
   dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
   ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime, DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

Then when you instantiate and import the class:

```
 val schema = DBSchemaV2(driver)
 import schema._
 import schema.driver.api._
```

this mapping will come along for a ride. That way you'll be able to use the ExtensionMethods in slick.

Answer (score 0):

```
  implicit val getEmailResult = GetResult(r => Email(Some(r.nextLong), r.nextString, r.nextString,
  r.nextString, new DateTime(r.nextTimestamp.getTime)))

  def last24Hours(address: String): Future[Vector[Email]] = {
    val r = sql"""SELECT id, email, uuid, address, datain FROM email 
      WHERE DATE_ADD(datain, INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= NOW() AND address = $address """
      .as[Email]
    db.run(r)
  }
```

Comment: this was my way of avoiding the problem i couldn't solve